How to find a transaction in the ton blockchain by boc (Bag of Cells)
I need help to find a transaction in the TON blockchain by boc (Bag of Cells).
Documentation https://docs.ton.org/develop/dapps/ton-connect/transactions says that it's possible but cannot find a way how todo that.
I can parse boc in java but it doesn't help me I cannot find transactions or messages by hash of boc
Cell.fromBocBase64("te6cckEBAwEA4QAC44gBZUPZ6qi8Dtmm1cot1P175lXUARlUVwlfMM19lkERK1oCUB3RqDxAFnPpeo191X/jiimn9Bwnq3zwcU/MMjHRNN5sC5tyymBV3SJ1rjyyscAjrDDFAIV/iE+WBySEPP9wCU1NGLsfcvVgAAACSAAYHAECAGhCAFlQ9nqqLwO2abVyi3U/XvmVdQBGVRXCV8wzX2WQRErWoAmJaAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAGZCAFlQ9nqqLwO2abVyi3U/XvmVdQBGVRXCV8wzX2WQRErWnMS0AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAADkk4U")

Thanks

import TonWeb from "tonweb";
const msg = {
boc: "te6cckEBAwEA4QAC44gBZUPZ6qi8Dtmm1cot1P175lXUARlUVwlfMM19lkERK1oCUB3RqDxAFnPpeo191X/jiimn9Bwnq3zwcU/MMjHRNN5sC5tyymBV3SJ1rjyyscAjrDDFAIV/iE+WBySEPP9wCU1NGLsfcvVgAAACSAAYHAECAGhCAFlQ9nqqLwO2abVyi3U/XvmVdQBGVRXCV8wzX2WQRErWoAmJaAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAGZCAFlQ9nqqLwO2abVyi3U/XvmVdQBGVRXCV8wzX2WQRErWnMS0AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAADkk4U"
};
const msgBody = TonWeb.utils.base64ToBytes(msg.boc);
const cell:any = TonWeb.boc.Cell.oneFromBoc(msgBody);
const slice =cell.beginParse();
// Start parsing with something like const op = slice.loadUint(32);
if (!op.eq(new TonWeb.utils.BN(0x7362d09c))) continue; // op == transfer_notification

You can check the Jetton's opcodes with Tonscan, for example, for usdt, https://tonscan.org/address/EQCxE6mUtQJKFnGfaROTKOt1lZbDiiX1kCixRv7Nw2Id_sDs#source , check op-codes.fc and you will see the following
;; common

const op::transfer = 0xf8a7ea5;
const op::transfer_notification = 0x7362d09c;
const op::internal_transfer = 0x178d4519;
const op::excesses = 0xd53276db;
const op::burn = 0x595f07bc;
const op::burn_notification = 0x7bdd97de;

const op::provide_wallet_address = 0x2c76b973;
const op::take_wallet_address = 0xd1735400;

const op::top_up = 0xd372158c;

const error::invalid_op = 72;
const error::wrong_op = 0xffff;
const error::not_owner = 73;
const error::not_valid_wallet = 74;
const error::wrong_workchain = 333;

;; jetton-minter

const op::mint = 0x642b7d07;
const op::change_admin = 0x6501f354;
const op::claim_admin = 0xfb88e119;
const op::upgrade = 0x2508d66a;
const op::call_to = 0x235caf52;
const op::change_metadata_uri = 0xcb862902;

;; jetton-wallet

const op::set_status = 0xeed236d3;

const error::contract_locked = 45;
const error::balance_error = 47;
const error::not_enough_gas = 48;
const error::invalid_message = 49;

Not an expert, just some sharing what works for me
